# Guideline/rule for logging when using 3rd party libraries/framework?

Tags: ros, best-practices, logging

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For example, when writing a plugin for `rqt` (aka ROS GUI) that's inherently dependent on `Qt`, I think there's 2 choice for logging, since both `ROS` and `Qt` have logging mechanism.

In the cases like above, which logging mechanism should we use? Or in which case do we stick to `ROS` or to the others?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46698/guideline/rule-for-logging-when-using-3rd-party-libraries/framework?/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2012-10-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Self response. Not a `ROS` general guideline/rule/best practice or anything but I found this could be a good example:

[`rqt`'s API review](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rqt/Reviews/2012-06-20_API_Review) says,

```
2. Question / concerns / comments
:
2
(Dirk) I would propose to not integrate logging functionality into ROS GUI. All ROS plugins can use the ROS-specific logging functionality provided by the client libraries. A plugin similar to rxconsole can then be used to show/filter all these messages. Non-ROS plugins can decide if they want to use logging library or stick with the Qt functions qDebug, qWarning, qCritical. 
:
3. Conclusion
:
ROS GUI does not provide logging funtionality but relies on either the Qt or the ROS logging functions (following the KISS principle)
```

So at least `rqt` doesn't restrict which logging system to use.

Meanwhile in `qt_gui_core`, `Qt`'s command `qDebug` is in use http://goo.gl/Oz5uU.

Don't know if this attitude holds for the entire `ROS` system though.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2012-10-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0